# How can I share a photo with skype using the default photo app (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, skype, photos, sharing

On Windows 10, there used to be an option in the default photo app to share a photo with skype. If you clicked on "share", you could select "Skype" which would open a small dialog where you could select the contact or group to send the photo to. The same option used to be available in the "Snip and Sketch" tool.

However, I am not able to find this option anymore. For example, if I want to share a cutout screenshot directly in this app, I only have the following options:

[image]

This is what I see when clicking "Share" in the Snip and Sketch app - it is nearly identical to the photo app. Note how I cannot select the Skype app.

I am using Windows 10 Home 1909. From what I can remember, there was no major update in which this option could have been removed.

So:

1. Was the option to share such a screenshot or photo with Skype removed?
2. If no, how can I enable it?

Comment: The option doesn't exist in 1809, are you sure Snip and Sketch, had this feature?  **1809 was released 2 years ago.**  Have you tried the `Get apps in Store` option and selecting Skype?  I don't have access to a system that can install applications from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, I use Version **19**09

Comment: I know that;  **I AM RUNNING** 1809.  Which is relevant since the option would have had to exist before 1809.  Snip & Sketch wasn't even an application before 1809.  **Your likely thinking of Screen Sketch which was a feature before 1809.**

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure if I am just confused, but it seems to me that you misread my Version number. It's 1909 (so, from last year) (mayber I am also just misunderstanding what you mean). The problem is that I already have skype installed from the store, so I cannot again download it from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117259/discussion-between-ramhound-and-jonas).

Comment: I installed skype but not launched and when click share, it only listed following options in the Photos App:copy files and some other apps like Snip&Sktech.  Haven't find other settings to customize the applications to be shared. You may also check if Skype itself has any configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly answer my question, but it is a workaround that I personally consider to be even better than the original way that I described above (which seems to be "lost").

If you have a photo opened in the photos app, you can simply copy it (either by right-clicking or "Share" -> "copy file") and then paste it in skype by going to the bar where you would type a message and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. This opens a dialog where you can add more files or simply press enter to send the photo.

Even more convenient, if you use the Snip and Sketch app to shreenshot a part of your screen, this image is already copied to clipboard, so you can simply paste it into Skype. I also found this to work with other messaging software such as WhatsApp Web.